# Can I move the sitename-le-ssl.conf contents into sitename.conf and delete the sitename-le-ssl.conf in my Virtual Host setup on Ubuntu / Apache?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, ssl, apache-virtualhost

I have this free SSL certificate from Let'sEncrypt and it works just fine.

But there's quite many files inside my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` directory and I'd like to delete / merge some of them, to only have 4 files there:

- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mroesler.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/firstsnow.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/converse.conf`

Currently I've got this many files:

```
michal@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -lah /etc/apache2/sites-available/
total 36K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul  8 14:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K Jun 16 21:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.6K Nov 24  2022 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.6K Nov 24  2022 000-default-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul  8 14:50 converse.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.2K Oct  1  2020 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  168 Jun 15 02:58 firstsnow.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  346 Jun 15 02:25 firstsnow-le-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  164 Jun 15 02:59 mroesler.conf
```

I'd like to move the contents of `firstsnow-le-ssl.conf` which is:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName firstsnow.dev
  ServerAlias www.firstsnow.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/first
  
  
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstsnow.dev/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstsnow.dev/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

into the `firstsnow.conf` file, that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName firstsnow.dev
      ServerAlias www.firstsnow.dev
      DocumentRoot /var/www/first
  
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I'd like to put it beneath the content, that's already inside the `firstsnow.conf` in a way described and shown [here](https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-apache/).
But I'm not sure, what should I do with the `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines.  Can I just not include them in the combined `firstsnow.conf` file.

Will my Let'sEncrypt SSL certificate still work??

Will something like this work?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName firstsnow.dev
   ServerAlias www.firstsnow.dev
   DocumentRoot /var/www/first

   Redirect permanent / https://firstsnow.dev/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName firstsnow.dev
   ServerAlias www.firstsnow.dev
   DocumentRoot /var/www/first


   <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.firstsnow.dev'">
      Redirect permanent / https://firstsnow.dev/
   </If>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstsnow.dev/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/firstsnow.dev/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Is it correct - as the content of `firstsnow.conf` after I'll delete the `firstsnow-le-ssl.conf` file ??